# Getting empty friends list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends, facebook-permissions

My goal is to get a list of user facebook friends using Facebook Graph API. At least those, who have used social authentication on my website

I have read, that after v2.0 I can get only a list of friends, if the following conditions are met:

> A user access token with user_friends permission is required to view
>   the current person's friends.
>       This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.
>       If a friend of the person declines the user_friends permission, that friend will not show up in the friend list for this person.

When I get a token and check

```
/v2.5/me/permissions
```

Result:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "permission": "user_friends",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "public_profile",
      "status": "granted"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am testing 2 user accounts, who are friends. I have used both for login in my web application using Facebook Login.
But when I  do

```
v2.5/me/friends
```

Result:

```
{
  "data": [
  ],
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 1
  }
}
```

What is the reason of empty friends set?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all those friends authorized your App with `user_friends` too. If they only authorized without `user_friends`, they will not show up. The response looks like it worked correctly.

Sidenote: It is not allowed to have 2 user accounts on Facebook, you can only have one account - with your real name.

Comment: How can I check if friends authorized my App with user_friends? Where can it be checked?

Comment: ask your friends if they authorized it, or check their access token. in any case, if they don´t show up in the list from /me/friends, they did not authorize it.

Comment: You are right. There is no user_friends permission. But it's impossible to check it, because there are only 2 options (public_profile and email). If I press edit permissions I see only these two.
But it supposed to be enabled by default and I saw green light on it in settings.

Comment: where exactly do you "edit permissions"? you have to implement a proper login process with the user_friends scope.

Comment: When I use an account of a friend I press facebook button in my web-app, then print email/password in popup. then I get a page with `continue as ***` and `will receive the following info: your public profile and email address.`. I click the link `edit the info you provide` and I see only 2 permissions available: `public profile` and `email address`. There is no permission `user_friends` to choose

Comment: then there is something wrong with your login process